# I am beginner, and have a question related to plotting in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python.

I wanted to know the syntax for a problem

Suppose I want to plot a quantity `x = (constant with a fixed given value) * ln (1+z) versus z` (which varies from c to d)

How do I define the variables x and z, how do I input an 'ln' function

I have imported `numpy`, `scipy` and `matplotlib`, but do not know how to proceed thereafter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already imported numpy, here is just another answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_coeff = 10
c = 0
d = 100
z = [i for i in range(c, d)]
x = [x_coeff * np.log(1+v) for i, v in enumerate(z)]
plt.plot(z, x)
plt.show()
```

It's always better to check the documents, and give out your first try:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html

You might also need to understand "list comprehension".
It's a beautiful and convenient way to create list in python.

Answer (score 0):

For plotting a curve, you need two lists, one of them is domain on x axis and the other is range points on y-axis. first we take a  constant as input,using python inbuilt input function and make sure that it is int, use math library and log function to do log as need.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = int(input("enter a value for constant : "))
c,d = 0,100
xvals = list(range(c,d,1)) # start,end,step
print(xvals)
yvals = [a*math.log(1+x) for x in xvals]
print(yvals)

plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
plt.show()
```